# Unity exported .fbx is not compatible with Blender

Tags: unity, .fbx

I follow the instruction in https://youtu.be/gqJTjuyNfh8, import the .fbx with character (from https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft-Rocketbox/tree/master/Assets/Avatars/Professions/Business_Female_01 ) and animation (from https://www.mixamo.com/#/ ) into the Unity and export the .fbx with model and animation. Then I import the .fbx into the Blender and find the mesh is distorted.

Please see the [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gHePVMqL6U9fac-EnBYI3E45Afqt0SlA/view?usp=sharing) here and *Assets* hierarchy in Unity below.
[image]

First, I drag the *Shoved Reaction With Spin.fbx* under Assets/Avatars/Business_Female_01/Export into the *Scene* and then drag the *mixamo.com* animation into the the *Shoved Reaction With Spin* of the left Hierarchy window.

[image]

[image]

Then, I click the *Play* button and the character runs.
[image]

To export the .fbx, under Window/Package Manager, I install the FBX Exporter. Then I select the *Shoved Reaction With Spin* in the *Hierarchy* window and click *Export To FBX…* under GameObject button. The *Shoved Reaction With Spin.fbx* can be exported.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

To import the .fbx into the Blender 2.82a, under File/Import, *FBX(.fbx)* is selected. The imported mesh is shown below and it is distorted.

[image]
[image]

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try testing the FBX and import it back into Unity?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie, yes, importing FBX back into Unity works. Now I found that the hierarchy of the model and the animation does not match. But I have no idea about how to adjust the hierarchy.